# Azure C# EventHubClient mock for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-eventhub

I am writing an event publisher for our application which internally uses [Azure C# EventHubClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0).

I want to unit test that my event gets translated correctly into EventData object (Properties + Body) as well as some other features. Long story short, I need some way to create a mock for EventHubClient. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a simple way of doing that:

- EventHubClient does not implement any relevant interface so using something like Moq or NSubstitute to create a mock will not work.
- EventHubClient is an abstract class with internal constructor so I cannot extend it and create a custom mock.

In theory, I could create a wrapper interface and class around the methods I want to use, but it means having more code to maintain. Does anybody know about a better way of unit testing with EventHubClient?

Comment: Take a look at how they test it and see if it sheds some light on the subject https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/tree/dev/test/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Tests

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the tip. They are loading connection string for real Event Hub from environment variables so it's more like integration test... I guess it makes sense for their use case.

Comment: @Nkosi In the end, I found the answer [in the repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/issues/24): the unit test friendliness should be coming soon.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft is big into "soon" - they've only been rejecting PR's thus far.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a simple wrapper around the `EventHubClient` and mocked that up instead.

```
public class EventHubService : IEventHubService
{
    private EventHubClient Client { get; set; }

    public void Connect(string connectionString, string entityPath)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
            {
                EntityPath = entityPath
            };

        Client =  EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
    }

    public async void Disconnect()
    {
        await Client.CloseAsync();
    }

    public Task SendAsync(EventData eventData)
    {
        return Client.SendAsync(eventData);
    }
}
```

And then testing is easy: `var eventHubService = new Mock<IEventHubService>();`